# get php variable by a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I've got 4 PHP variables, and I have 1 Javascript variable with the name of one of those 4 PHP variables, how can reference it?

```php
$p1 = ...
$p2 = ...
$p3 = ...
$p4 = ...

<script>
    var myoption = 'p1';
    var myarray = <?= $p1 ?>;
    console.log(myarray);
</script>
```

In this case instead of setting myarray to `$p1`, I want to do it with myoption, once myoption can be p2 or p3

Comment: If myoption is going to be set dynamically in js then you'll have to use something like ajax to get the value of the variable you want.

Comment: got it, and for example can I set the js variable to a php function return?

Comment: You need to understand what runs at what point, first PHP is run / executed / interpreted, then the result of the php file is returned to the client where the JavaScript may be executed.

Comment: yes, in this case the php variable is already set, I just need what is there, has the same order that above

Comment: When, where, and how does `myoption` vary? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70634183/edit) to show more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a PHP array, `json_encode` it into your Javascript, like this:

```
$p1 = ...
$p2 = ...
$p3 = ...
$p4 = ...

$myPHPArray = [
    'p1' => $p1,
    'p2' => $p2,
    'p3' => $p3,
    'p4' => $p4
];

<script>
    var myoption = 'p1';
    var myarray = <?php echo json_encode($myPHPArray) ?>;
    console.log(myarray[myoption]);
</script>
```